# Run event in Nebular's NbTabset in Angular 2

Tags: angular, tabs, nebular, nebula

How could I execute an event in `NbTabset` in `nebular` from `angular 2`

in the documentation that is not detailed, I would appreciate your help, whether or not that can execute a `function` in the `NbTabset`

```
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-body>

    <nb-tabset>
      <nb-tab tabTitle="Mujeres" (click)="onEvento()">
        <p>Aquí lógica de Mujeres </p>
      </nb-tab>
      <nb-tab tabTitle="Varones" (click)="onEvento()">
        <p>Aquí lógica de varones </p>
      </nb-tab>
    </nb-tabset>

  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,its possible to emit **changeTab** event `NbTabset` in nebular.Below is the code snippet and a  [sample stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nebular-1236-tsesrd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
  <nb-card>
  <nb-card-body>
    <nb-tabset  (changeTab)="onEvento($event)">
      <nb-tab tabTitle="Mujeres">
      <div>
        <p>Aquí lógica de Mujeres </p>
        </div>
      </nb-tab>
      <nb-tab tabTitle="Varones">
        <p>Aquí lógica de varones </p>
      </nb-tab>
    </nb-tabset>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

In component

```
onEvento(e){
    console.log(e.tabTitle)
  }
```